# How to make Chrome extension save the current tab into a desired folder as .url?

Tags: javascript, url, google-chrome-extension, save

I want to create a Chrome extension that, when activated, brings a popup where the user can type a desired folder and press enter, which would save a link to the current tab into that folder.

I want to replace bookmarks with these .url links in a Dropbox folder "Links". So in the extension popup, one should be able to type for example "Programming\Javascript", which would save a link to the current tab into a Dropbox folder "...\Dropbox\Links\Programming\Javascript". The popup could also show the folder structure in the Links folder so the user can easily see at a glance what folder the link should go to.

I am completely new to Javascript and asking for general advice (I know only Python). Is this actually something that can be done, would you have any tips on what methods specifically I should be looking at? Or has this already been done? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Extensions can't write to local folders. Extensions can 1) download a file to the default downloads directory or its subdirectory, 2) invoke a separate external program via [nativeMessaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) which will do anything the OS permits. It seems the 2nd option might work for you - see the python demo linked in the docs.

Comment: I believe extensions can write to local folders by using symlinks?

Comment: The only place where extensions can really write directly is the sandboxed HTML5 file system with obfuscated file names - supported in Chrome only last time I checked. Theoretically you can symlink there but I didn't test it so maybe Chrome won't resolve them or maybe it'll be buggy.

Comment: Ok, I guess this idea may not be so feasible then. I just need a better way to save links than dragging the url to folder by hand, and I don't like how bookmarks work. Need to be able to go through lots of tabs and quickly save the important ones to the right places and close the rest.

Comment: Well, if your users are willing to keep a symlink in their default downloads directory pointing to their bookmarks directory, you can use chrome.downloads API and specify a save-to path like `symlinkname/path-in-target/name.ext`